# Ubuntu 16.04 apache conf file issue

Tags: 16.04, localhost, apache2.4

Today I found that my existing `apache.conf` file rename to `apache.conf.dpkg-old` and generate a new `apache.conf` file in `/etc/apache` folder.
what is the reason?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

When the `apache` package (or any other package) is updated/upgraded by `apt` (e.g. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` or the unattended updates) and the update/upgrade contains changes to the configuration file, `dpkg` creates a backup of the old configuration file.

When the upgrade/update is executed manually (e.g. with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`), `dpkg` asks, if the changes should be applied to configuration file. In your case, it look like the [unattended security updates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates) have performed the update and applied the changes automatically.